# Plone: processForm() deletes my Archetype field

Tags: plone, zope, archetypes

I've written a product that uses an ATFolderSchema. The schema contains a costum archetypes field.

I implemented an edit form using content_edit. It works fine, but if i call content_edit, the content of my costum archetypes field is deleted. I could figure out that the function call `new_context.processForm()` in Archetypes/skins/archetypes/content_edit_impl.py causes this problem.
Unfortunately I can't find any information about processForm() in the internet.

I use Plone 4.1.6 and Archetypes 1.7.14.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `processForm` method is defined on Archetypes [BaseObject](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/c3cdddce6abba871744c2a88bbfed9fbbcc9ca02/Products/Archetypes/BaseObject.py#L653)
It basically handles the event triggering + creationFlag.

Th code you mentioned is in [`_processForm`](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/c3cdddce6abba871744c2a88bbfed9fbbcc9ca02/Products/Archetypes/BaseObject.py#L589) called by `processForm`

You can place a debugger for example on line [600](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/c3cdddce6abba871744c2a88bbfed9fbbcc9ca02/Products/Archetypes/BaseObject.py#L600)

your field has to be in `fields` and the data in `form`.

My best guess so far is, since you have your own `content_edit`, that you have a naming issue.

You can test this by temporary disable (remove) your custom `content_edit` and check if your data is stored on the object.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! I don't use an own `content_edit`, I just call it in my form metadata. But I could figure out, where my problem is: I've written a costum widget `process_form` method for my costum archetype field, which can't handle the new requirements. So I have to fix that. Thanks a lot again :)